# Centos server strange error

Tags: ubuntu

error in my server:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_20fe_1.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error is pretty clear. Go inside /tmp and see what is taking up the disk space.
You can install ncdu to see summary of disk usage in that folder.
Then delete what you don't need an restart MySQL

Also, 1 G is not enough for a temp folder in a production environment. You should consider expanding it.

Comment: thank you, how I can expand that tmp folder? I think this is the best idea, I have access to whm too if this will be much easy

Comment: I highly advise (if you have enough ram) to make tmp a tmpfs (so it is stored inside the ram). However, right now it's stored on a hard drive, so you need to extend the partition it is using: lvresize -r -L+xG /dev/mapper/vg-tmp - this will increase the size if you have enough space

Comment: @Robert if you don't have enough space on the disk, please check this form: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55593

Comment: Hi thank you I have enough memory ram: 32GB, I try to use your command and the output is:  WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
  Invalid argument for --size: +xG
  Error during parsing of command line.

Comment: I fix the error from now I just delete one folder there, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @DreamWave - If you make a ramdisk, you are taking away from other caching that MySQL does.  It is counterproductive.

Comment: @RickJames it depends on the machine I guess. MySQL doesn't need an endless supply of RAM. On a server with 16 G there's plenty of space for temp in the RAM.

Comment: It also depends on the application, of course - it might also need 16 G of RAM :D

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from [MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_disk_full). Partition of MySQL does not have enough disk space.
Free up disk space on the partition, check items on a partition and remove unnecessary files. You can check size via `df -h` and `ls -lh` and remove files which you don't need or increase disk size.

Comment: MySQL is probably under `/`, which has gobs of room.  Rephrase your answer.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a `VARIABLE` called `tmpdir` that controls where to put tmp tables.  It is probably set to `/tmp`.  But it can be changed to some other directory.  Make on hanging somewhere under `/`; that will give it space.  More info:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html

Also, check for "cross joins".  If you have a `SELECT` that `JOINs` tables, but with out any qualification on how the tables are relate, you may have a "cross join".  Two million-row tables in a cross join would create a temporary table with a trillion rows.  This would be a mess.